# VBA close blank workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I found this question asked before, but it was never answered. I have some VBA code that formats different files and outputs them onto an Excel spreadsheet, and then saves copies to two different directories. However, the trouble I'm having is that it leaves an empty workbook open and I don't know how to close it. I have tried Workbooks.Close,  and Application.Quit but neither worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the part of my code that I'm referring to:

```
sSaveAsFilePath = "\\Filesrv02\test\remit" + ".csv"
sSaveAsFilePath2 = "\\Filesrv02\backup\remit" + Format(Date, "mmddyy") + ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ChDir "\\Filesrv02\test"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=sSaveAsFilePath, _
       FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
      'ActiveWorkbook.Close False

ChDir "\\Filesrv02\Backup"
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=sSaveAsFilePath2, _
       FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Kind of hard to display "done" if you want excel to close completely? And why two displayalearts=false?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to close the main project from within it's code.

Comment: is the code called from a separate workbook than the ones you wish to create and close? And why is the empty workbook even there? It's best to qualify each workbook you want to work with to a variable of `Workbook` type then work directly with that, and eliminate the `ActiveWorkbook` statement. If you do that, it would be easy to see where your problem lies.

Comment: @ZygD - It is very possible to close the main project from within it's own code. The code will stop executing, but it's possible to do that.

Comment: oops the second display alerts should be true, just did a copy/paste and forgot to change. Thanks Scott, I will give that a try.

Comment: The code isn't called in another workbook, and what it does is creates a copy of the spreadsheet only and saves those copies in two different directories. For some reason, it creates/leaves a blank instance of Excel that has nothing in it, and I am unable to close it even after adding a vbScript to kill excel. Strange. Thanks everyone, will post on here if I come up with anything.

Comment: @justkrys - thanks for the information. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only copying a sheet out of your workbook to save in different locations, you can just copy that sheet out of the workbook and save it to another location. This will leave your original workbook intact, and will not make a mysterious blank workbooks. Also, note how I qualified all the workbooks and worksheets with variables.

```
sSaveAsFilePath = "\\Filesrv02\test\remit" + ".csv"
sSaveAsFilePath2 = "\\Filesrv02\backup\remit" + Format(Date, "mmddyy") + ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Workbook, wbC As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ws.Sheets("mySheet") 'change name as needed

'create and save test version
ws.Copy

Set wbC = ActiveWorkbook

With wbC
    .SaveAs Filename:=sSaveAsFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
End With

'create and save backup version
ws.Copy

Set wbC = ActiveWorkbook

With wbC
    .SaveAs Filename:=sSaveAsFilePath2, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

MsgBox ("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workbook before save

```
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=sSaveAsFilePath, _
           FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```